# How to store some part of word after "-" sign by using cookies or a SQL Server query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, cookies

I have a question I want to store all the characters after "**-**" sign to my cookies using c# and asp.net. Example: **rock star-games** so here I want to store "**games**" word in cookies as it is after - sign so is it possible or is there any other solution using SQL Server etc. I have searched for many days but could not find any solution for storing some part of word in cookies.

Comment: What is is that you are having problems with exactly? Getting a part of a string? Storing a value in a cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To separate a string, you can just do

```
  string[] split = mystring.Split('-');
  string afterthedash = split[1];
```

You'd also want to confirm there *is* a dash in the string, and if the `string[]` is longer than 2 items, combine the extras however they should be into just two, etc.

But the above is the basics of how to do it.

To then go on to storing them in cookies/mssql/etc., that's a whole different question and it would help if you could clarify exactly what part is holding you back.

Comment: yes thanks for the answer but i had already solved it using          string from = tags.Text;
string lastFragment = from.Split('-').Last();